# nodejs express route cant send req to function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route which will work fine if I implement it with method 1:

```
//METHOD 1
router.post('/my_competitive_landscape', ensureAuthenticated, async function (req, res) {
  let startDate = req.body.startDate
  console.log('METHOD1 startDate=', startDate)
  res.status(200).send('DONE');
})
```

Where when I make a post request to the route, it runs the function. I am trying to this function so it can be called elsewhere by changing my route to work like method2:

```
//METHOD 2
router.post('/my_competitive_landscape', ensureAuthenticated, myCompFunc(req, res));

async function myCompFunc(req, res){
  let startDate = req.body.startDate
  console.log('METHOD2 startDate=', startDate)
  res.status(200).send('DONE');
}
```

So that when I make a post request to the route, it sends req and res to the myCompFunc function. The problem is that when I run Method2, my code wont even run because it throws me this error:

```
router.post('/my_competitive_landscape', ensureAuthenticated, myCompFunc(req, res));
                                                                         ^

ReferenceError: req is not defined
```

Saying req is not defined. I'm able to send req to a function in my Method1 just fine, why can I not send req using method2?

**EDIT** I can make it work by changing it to use `myCompFunc`, but is thee a way I can specify multiple vars including but not limited to req and res? Like:

```
//method3
router.post('/my_competitive_landscape', ensureAuthenticated, myCompFunc(req.body.startDate, "otherVar", res));

async function myCompFunc(startDate, var2, res){
  console.log('METHOD3 startDate=', startDate, ', var2=', var2)
  res.status(200).send('DONE');
}
```

Comment: You just want `router.post('/my_competitive_landscape', ensureAuthenticated, myCompFunc);`

Comment: you are executing your function with parameters `req`, `res` that do not exist. what you want is to pass the function as a parameter, and then the caller of the function will pass `req` and `res`

Answer (score 0):

> Just remove the call of your function when you declare the route and declare the function before the route. Like this:

```
async function myCompFunc(req, res){
  let startDate = req.body.startDate
  console.log('METHOD2 startDate=', startDate)
  res.status(200).send('DONE');
}

router.post('/my_competitive_landscape', ensureAuthenticated, myCompFunc);
```

Comment: thanks , is there any way I can specify more vars ? Something like `//method3
router.post('/my_competitive_landscape', ensureAuthenticated, myCompFunc(req.body.startDate, "otherVar", res));

async function myCompFunc(startDate, var2, res){
  console.log('METHOD3 startDate=', startDate, ', var2=', var2)
  res.status(200).send('DONE');
}` still causes the req not defined error

Comment: figured out a way around this, by calling my function like: ` let tempResp = myCompFunc({body:{'startDate':'xqc'}}, null)` works